# Angular swagger-ui with endpoint to download file not working

Tags: angular, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a angular swagger ui page in my application which works similar to the swagger  documentation for API. I use the angular swagger ui package in this link ->https://github.com/ostranme/angular-swagger-ui-example

Everything works fine except for the download file endpoint. There is a download file endpoint which on **Try now** displays a **Download {filename.extn}** link clicking on which the file will be downloaded. This works only on the swagger page in the API but not in the equivalent angular swagger ui. In the angular swagger ui, it displays **Download** link clicking on it downloads a file but with a blob file name like this -> *application_octet-stream_Download_id=#&filename=Test.txt&originalFilename=Test.txt_blob_http___{hostname}_{portnumber}_b4e7338a-33c6-4152-b6f5-8ddec8cec2d125*.

Due to this, we have to rename the downloaded file appropriately to open the file.

I want the same functionality as in swagger page in the API to download the file with the appropriate file name and extension.

Is there a way to fix this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the Swagger UI version a) in the API; b) in your Angular page? To see the version, open the browser dev tools, switch to the Console tab, and evaluate `versions`.

Comment: @Helen : The angular swagger ui version - "swagger-ui-dist": "^3.37.2",  in the API 
 the version of Swashbuckle is 5.6.0 and swagger in console is swaggerApi.swaggerVersion = 2.0.

Comment: Can you try `swagger-ui-dist` v. 4.18.2 and see if it resolve the issue?

Comment: @Helen : updating 'swagger-ui-dist' to v4.18.2 is not resolving this issue. Deleted node_modules, ran npm install again. Still facing the same download link issue.

Comment: For now I have fixed by handling this in the swagger API oncompletion event to set the value of the download link.